# How to make a click event on a text JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
      var $tweet = $('<div class = tweet></div>');
      $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message + ' ' + tweet.created_at);
```

I'm exploring JQuery and I'm generating tweets or messages by users. Is it possible to do a click event on a certain string on tweet.user? I assume not because it's not a jquery object. My line of thinking is that I have to make a separate `$user` object and reference the attribute of `tweet.user` and then I can have a click event on `$user`. Is that the right line of thinking? Just looking for some guidance!

Comment: Just on `tweet.user` or the whole string `'@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message + ' ' + tweet.created_at`?

Comment: Just on the specific user so `tweet.user`

Comment: include it in span and target it?

Comment: Did my answer address your issue?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Yes, thank you! I'll check it as the correct answer

Comment: :) That wasn't mine, you marked the one which adds a listener on the whole  string while you stated in the comments that you needed click only on `tweet.user`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Haha, fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.html()` and `.on()`

```
var $tweet = $('<div class="tweet"></div>');
$tweet.html('<span class="tweet-user">@' + tweet.user + '</span>: ' + tweet.message + ' ' + tweet.created_at);

...

$(document).on("click", ".tweet-user", function(){ ... })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$().html()` to include html having span with class then target it and set on click

```js
let tweet={
  user:'Supercool',
  message:'Hey im cool ',
  created_at:'Just now'
}
$('.tweet')
.html(`
<span class="user">@${tweet.user} :  ${tweet.message} <br> ${tweet.created_at}</span>`
);

$('.tweet>.user').click(()=>console.log("Im clicked bro"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = tweet></div>
```